# Mount error: mount failed: File exists

Tags: mount, fstab, unmounting, automounting

I am unable to mount my USB:

```
$ mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: mount /dev/sdb1 on /mnt failed: File exists
```

What is the origin of this error and how do I mount my USB?

The partition `/dev/sdb1` is not in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Can you give the output of `lsblk` please.

Comment: I got the same error. [Here](https://pastebin.com/E7ZAkW6h) is my output.

Comment: Any news on this? I have the exact same issue but cannot find a solution.

Comment: Only thing I found is the following post, but as far as I can see it is all about btrfs snapshots while I am only using a normal btrfs volume. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537029/error-for-mount-system-call-failed-file-exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error for \`mount\`: \`system call failed: File exists.\`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537029/error-for-mount-system-call-failed-file-exists)

Answer (score 4):

the error means  '/dev/sdb1' has already been mounted. 
in this case it is because you can't mount a filesystem to /mnt you have to specify a folder

```
su umount /dev/sdb1
cd /mnt
su mkdir usbstick
su mount  /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usbstick
exit
```

add it to fstab

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/usbstick fat32 noauto,users,rw,umask=0 0 0
```

change fat32 to whatever the filesystem on the stick is

Comment: If the problem was that `/dev/sdb1` is already mounted, the error would be EBUSY, not EEXIST. You can always mount to `/mnt`, even if it has subdirectories; it would hide the subdirectories, but that wouldn't prevent the mounting.

Comment: there was no error specified by OP so you are guessing.  and no you cannot always mount a fs to /mnt  it depends on OS and sysadmin. letting any process mount a fs is a security hole.  fstabs can be exploited.

Comment: @μολὼν.λαβέ I've posted my output as a comment on the question. It shows the error appearing when trying to mount on a freshly created directory.

Comment: @Tom Hale what is your mount point?  what permissions are you using?

Comment: @μολὼν.λαβέ As shown, the first mount point tried was existing, then a new directory was created as mountpoint, and that mount also failed (both via `sudo`). umask=0022. It seems a transitory error. I have a btrfs filesystem with errors. Rebooting fixed the mount issue.

Comment: @Tom Hale that's very weird but the command should always work, from most *nix flavors to osx. if it doesn't i suspect the filesystem or driver is probably corrupt